# Forwarding keystroke to shell in Shell mode

Tags: emacs

Is there some way to forward a keystroke to the shell when using Shell mode?
In particular, I sometimes want to use CTRL+\ to sigkill a process, but Emacs intercepts it

Another problem is that I sometimes want Tab to get forwarded to the shell to get default tab completion.

Answer (score 3):

In general, `M-x term`, or even better, `M-x ansi-term`, give more complete emulators than `M-x shell`. Once you are in term-mode you can get into *char mode* with `C-c C-j` to interact with the terminal. Once you are in char mode, you should be able to use the terminal's tab completion and other terminal keyboard shortcuts. You can get back to the regular default *line mode* with `C-c C-k`.

You can read more about the differences between these modes [here](http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2010/11/01/running-shells-in-emacs-overview/)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. For instance, I ran `M-x multi-term` then in the terminal buffer, accidentally started another `emacs` instance. I still need a way to forward keystrokes, specifically leaders, such as `C-x C-s` to save my work and `C-x C-c` to exit the nested emacs w/o exiting from my original emacs.

Answer (score 1):

You can press Control-Q before any other key to treat that key literally.  So, C-q C-\ or C-q TAB should do what you want.

Comment: doesn't work. accidentally launched another `emacs` within a multi-term terminal buffer. When I press `C-q C-x C-s` the original emacs intercepts it still.